# Adding variables to a external URL in PHP

Tags: php, html, url, bioinformatics

I want to add variables that I set into an external link.

For example:

This is the external link

```
https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?hgsid=836970973_rJGr4Hntud9tPwgMncRaiAnedvci&org=D.+melanogaster&db=dm6&position=cac&pix=950
```

Where

**db** will be used for a variable and 
  **position** will be used for a variable

I defined the variables: $organism (this I just set manually) and $gene (this contain the result of a previous selection process, for example the result was: cac)

```
If ($genoma=='D_melanogaster'){  $organism='dm6'; $gene=$gene}

 echo '<a href="https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?hgsid=836970973_rJGr4Hntud9tPwgMncRaiAnedvci&org=D.+melanogaster&db="$organism"&position="$gene"&pix=950">Click here</a>';
```

But I haven't driven to the website.

How can I link variables to this link?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is being ended when you put the first quote mark for the variable. You should do either of these two

```
echo "<a href='https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?hgsid=836970973_rJGr4Hntud9tPwgMncRaiAnedvci&org=D.+melanogaster&db=$organism&position=$gene&pix=950'>Click here</a>";

echo "<a href='https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?hgsid=836970973_rJGr4Hntud9tPwgMncRaiAnedvci&org=D.+melanogaster&db=".$organism."&position=".$gene."&pix=950'>Click here</a>";
```